# How can I make Logitech a 4K PRO MAGNETIC WEBCAM work with a mid-2011 Mac mini?

Tags: macos, thunderbolt, mac-mini, webcam

I have a Logitech 4K PRO MAGNETIC WEBCAM which I bought to use with a mid-2011 Mac mini, 2.3 GHz, running High Sierra. 
I've used an Apple Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter and a Thunderbolt cable to plug the webcam in, using the Thunderbolt 2 port of the Mac mini.

It is built to work with the Apple Pro Display XDR. I inferred from the technical specs that it should work with other hardware like 2018 MacBook Pro, just not at 4K so I hope my inference holds for my Mac.

I hoped the adaptor would overcome the lack of a USB-C/Thunderbolt 3 port on my Mac mini; the Thunderbolt 3 to 2 adapter is fully bidirectional for many other devices.

https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/HMUC2Z/A/logitech-4k-pro-magnetic-webcam-for-pro-display-xdr
https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/4k-pro-magnetic-webcam

However, it does not work. If I run an app like Photo Booth it says, 'There is no connected camera.' I do not see the webcam in system information. Apparently, it should appear under Privacy settings, if nowhere else.

What can I do to make it work, please?

I appreciate that I'm not running the latest OS, however, the latest one is Catalina, and presumably the webcam will work on the version after Catalina, as well as continuing to work on Catalina, so I don't see 'latest OS' as being restrictive.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What precisely does not work? Do you see the device connected in system information when you get it connected? Make sure you edit the clarification into your post. Many people won’t see comments when they search for a question to answer.  Everything looks like you need a Mac from 2018 or newer and Catalina for this to work “by the book” so I’ve edited some detail I know to be true about your chosen adapter and specs

Comment: On the page you link to apple clearly states, Operating System: The latest version of macOS" Which is certainly not High Sierra. Also, I would imagine the device requires Thunderbolt-3. A message to Logitech should clear that up.

Comment: Thank you, bmike and Steve Chambers. I have added to the query as you bmike indicated, to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks, Steve Chambers. Yes, I've bought an adaptor that should work, but doesn't.
I have logged a question with Logitech Support, but I don't think they'll answer until Monday. Their system looks good.

Comment: Latest version of macOS is *very* specific. The monitor this webcam was designed for didn't exist before Catalina! So I'm betting *it just won't work unless you update to Catalina.* Also verify the webcam works, plug it into a USB3/Thunderbolt Mac. And **again** have you contacted Logitech support? It may not support thunderbolt 2.

Comment: Yes, I have logged a question with Logitech (I did say that above), but they don't seem to have people answering at the moment, only bots. Thank you, I see what you mean, that the latest is not High Sierra. To be fair to me, Logitech does supply an app for this webcam that is High Sierra compatible; I upgraded from Sierra today, hoping it would help; sadly, no. I would argue that 'Catalina and superseding versions of macOS' is more specific than 'latest version'.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Steve Chambers and bmike.
Logitech did respond after a little while, and advised that I return the webcam. I returned it to the Apple shop, which reimbursed me.

Answer (score 1):

This web cam will not work on the Mid-2011 Mac mini because it does not meet the system requirements.

Per the [Technical Specifications](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039707194-4K-Pro-Magnetic-Webcam-Technical-Specifications), the Logitech 4K Pro Magnetic Webcam (for the XDR Display) requires a **USB 3.1 Type C connection**.

[image: Logitech Pro 4K Tech Specs - Connection Type]
<sup>Image of connection type included in case URL goes stale in the future</sup>

Per the [Technical Specifications of the Mac mini](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP632?locale=en_US), it only has USB 2.0 ports.

#### Bottom Line

This webcam will work with *any* computer that supports a (minimum) USB 3.1 connection with a Type-C connector.  Note, it's not Thunderbolt, however a Thunderbolt 3 port will carry the USB 3.1 signal.  Thunderbolt 1 or 2 **do not** have support for USB.

It will also work with *any* computer with USB 3.1 including PCs.  Additionally, it will work with other displays as well, but it was designed for the XDR display.  Per the [FAQ](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040250073-FAQ-Stub-4K-PRO-MAGNETIC-WEBCAM):

> The webcam will work with other displays, however, you won’t be able to use the magnetic mount. It has been specifically designed for the Pro Display XDR. Additionally, the included cable’s length and connector angles have been optimized for this specific display.

Comment: Thanks, Allan. Mine has a Thunderbolt 2 port as well as USB ports. Still, the camera did not work through that port, despite the adapter I mentioned above.

Comment: It’s not going to, ever.   The cam  **requires** USB 3.1 and Thunderbolt 2 doesn’t support USB (any version) regardless of the adapter(s) you purchase.  The adapter you Reference doesn’t magically  give your Mac capabilities it didn’t come with initially.

Comment: Thanks, Allan. Hindsight shows that to be the case, basically, which is why I sent the webcam back, as I set out above.
I was reporting the resolution of the matter, rather than raising the question again.